# CSS Flexbox multi row/col

Tags: css, flexbox

Can you explain to me what i'm doing wrong or if i'm missing something?

I don't wanna use grid layout or add more containers inside.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
  <div>G</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
  display : flex;
  width: 320px;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.container  > div {
  align-self: start;
}
  
.img {
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
  
.container > div:not(.img) {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width : 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[trying to achieve this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RN2q.png)

[this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtEzX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything flexbox related and then add the following:

```css
.container > div:nth-child(n + 2) {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}

.img {
  ...
  float: left;
}
```

While flexbox is adaptable, the behavior you really need is `float` (if it could be done with flexbox, `float` would've been deprecated or obsolete by now).

### Example

Specific margins were set to position the `<div>`s as close to what is in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RN2q.png).

```css
.container {
  width: 320px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.container>div:nth-child(n + 2) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 1rem 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
  <div>G</div>
</div>
```

[image]